# No module named 'tensorflow' [3803] Failed to execute

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to build an app using Pyinstaller. When I try to execute the .exe I receive :

File "Detectare.py", line 3, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
[3803] Failed to execute script Detectare

However I have python3 with tensorflow installed and running successfully.
The .py script runs smoothly on my system. 
How can I make Pyinstaller "see" tensorflow ?

The CLI commands are : "pyi-makespec Detectare.py" to make the .spec file and then "Pyinstaller Detectare.spec"

This is the full log when I execute from "dist" folder :

Last login: Mon May 11 12:06:27 on ttys000
gabrielhuna@Gabriels-MacBook-Pro ~ % /Users/gabrielhuna/Desktop/Program\ 2/dist/Detectare/Detectare ; exit;
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Detectare.py", line 4, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
[6250] Failed to execute script Detectare

[Process completed]

And when I execute from the "build" folder :

Last login: Mon May 11 12:08:57 on ttys000
gabrielhuna@Gabriels-MacBook-Pro ~ % /Users/gabrielhuna/Desktop/Program\ 2/build/Detectare/Detectare ; exit;

[6274] Error loading Python lib '/Users/gabrielhuna/Desktop/Program 2/build/Detectare/Python': dlopen: 
dlopen(/Users/gabrielhuna/Desktop/Program 2/build/Detectare/Python, 10): image not found

[Process completed]

Comment: What is your current command line statement for pyinstaller?

Comment: PyInstaller 3.6 doesn't support tensorflow. Please either use the development version - which does - or wait for the next release (1 month or so).

Comment: The CLI commands are :   "pyi-makespec Detectare.py"  to make the .spec file and then "Pyinstaller Detectare.spec" @SPYBUG96

Comment: Thank you for suggesting this. I am using the dev version now but I have the same problem. When executing the "Pyinstaller Detectare.spec" CLI command the terminal shows at some point : 51075 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-tensorflow_core.python.py' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
55612 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow_core._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.nasnet" not found! And then 20 or so messages like that one above about some tensofllow module. @Legorooj

Comment: @AlexandruGabrielHuna can you edit and post the full build log - with the development version - and the traceback?

Comment: @Alexandru Gabriel Huna, Is your issue resolved  now? Else, Please can you try [this](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4400#issuecomment-551147137).

Comment: Which version of PyInstaller work with Python: 3.6.9 and TensorFlow 2.1?